# How do I know my whole android application is not running anymore or closed?

Tags: android, timer, runnable, timertask, ondestroy

I have a timer where I perform a task for instance, every 10 seconds.

The problem is I want to know my application has been closed already in any activity I am in, so I could end my runnable timer and the task within it. I successfully implemented using `onDestroy` on an activity but this is only for the current activity I am in, then I also tried `onTerminate` in my application class but It's not triggered and it's also discouraged.

So how could I do this? Is there an `onDestroy` equivalent in my Application class?

Comment: no, because in most case it is not to you to worry about the application being stopped or not, and also the very definition of this state is rather fuzzy

Comment: So how would I know when to stop the timer, because the task inside my timer still runs even if I already closed the application.

Comment: your timer is probably related to an activity ? or a list of activities ?

Comment: What do you mean list of activities? Anyway, the timer is inside `doInBackground` of an Asynctask with a `TimerTask` and `Runnable`

Comment: if it simply depends on one activity, stop it when you leave the app